# Two Reactive Picker Input, Retain Selection Previous Event Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, server

I am constructing a shiny app. In the UI I have one `selectInput` and one `pickerInput`. Of course the `pickerInput` depends on the `selectInput`. In the example below, I want to find a way how to preserve what has been selected in `pickerInput` when users change the `selectInput`.

In the example below, let's imagine a user who selects `Period 1: X to Z` and either `UK` or `USA` or both `UK` and `USA`. What I want is that if that user changes `Period 1: X to Z` to `Period 2: X to Y` that `UK` be automatically selected -- or stay selected -- (because `UK` is among the choices of `Period 2: X to Y`).

So, how to retain what has been selected in `pickerInput` when `input_period` changes.

Thank you!

```
choice_name <- c('UK','USA','UK','USA','BE','BE')
choice_id <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3)
period <- c('period1', 'period1', 'period2', 'period3', 'period3', 'period3')
data <- data.frame(choice_name, choice_id, period)

choices_picker <- unique(data$choice_id)
names(choices_picker) <- unique(data$choice_name)


ui <- bootstrapPage(                
  absolutePanel(left = 10, bottom = 10, draggable = TRUE, 
                selectInput(inputId = "input_period", label = "Period",
                            choices = c("Period 1: X to Z" = "period1", "Period 2: X to Y" = "period2", "Period 3: X to X" = "period3"),
                            selected = "period1"),
                pickerInput(inputId = "picker_cty",
                            label = "Select Country",
                            choices = choices_picker,
                            multiple = TRUE),
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Reactive pickerInput ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$input_period, {
    
    data1 <- data[data$period == input$input_period,]
    datau <- unique(data$choice_id)
    data1u <- unique(data1$choice_id)
    
    disabled_choices <- ifelse(datau %in% data1u, 0,1)
    
    # Generate reactive picker input
    updatePickerInput(session = session, 
                      inputId = "picker_cty",
                      choices = choices_picker,
                      choicesOpt = list(
                        disabled = disabled_choices,
                        style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                                       yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                       no = "")
                      ))
  }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select =` option.  Try this

```
choice_name <- c('UK','USA','UK','USA','BE','BE')
choice_id <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3)
period <- c('period1', 'period1', 'period2', 'period3', 'period3', 'period3')
data <- data.frame(choice_name, choice_id, period)
data2 <- data[data$period == "period1",]
choices_picker <- unique(data$choice_id)
names(choices_picker) <- unique(data$choice_name)

datau <- unique(data$choice_id)
data2u <- unique(data2$choice_id)

disabled_choicez <- ifelse(datau %in% data2u, 0,1)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  absolutePanel(left = 10, bottom = 10, draggable = TRUE,
                selectInput(inputId = "input_period", label = "Period",
                            choices = c("Period 1: X to Z" = "period1", "Period 2: X to Y" = "period2", "Period 3: X to X" = "period3"),
                            selected = "period1" ),
                pickerInput(inputId = "picker_cty",
                            label = "Select Country",
                            choices = choices_picker,
                            choicesOpt = list(
                              disabled = disabled_choicez,
                              style = ifelse(disabled_choicez,
                                             yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                             no = "")
                            ),
                            selected = character(0),
                            multiple = TRUE),
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({print(input$picker_cty)})

  # Reactive pickerInput ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$input_period, {

    data1 <- data[data$period == input$input_period,]
    datau <- unique(data$choice_id)
    data1u <- unique(data1$choice_id)

    disabled_choices <- ifelse(datau %in% data1u, 0,1)

    if (is.null(input$picker_cty)) selected = character(0)
    else {
      if (sum(data1u %in% input$picker_cty)>0) {
        selected = data1u[data1u %in% input$picker_cty]
      }else selected = character(0)
    }

    # Generate reactive picker input
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "picker_cty",
                      choices = choices_picker,
                      selected = selected,
                      choicesOpt = list(
                        disabled = disabled_choices,
                        style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                                       yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                       no = "")
                      ))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In that case, you want "Nothing selected" or USA only?

Comment: Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thank you @YBS!